# Thread synchronization problem in thread's procedure

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a question. I add the object to the map and in the thread call the run() procedure for all elements in the map.
I correctly understand that in this code there is a synchronization problem in the process procedure. Can I add a mutex? Given that this procedure is called in the thread?

```
class Network {

public:
  Network() {
    std::cout << "Network constructor" << std::endl;
  }

  void NetworkInit(const std::string& par1) {
    this->par1 = par1;
  }

  ~Network() {
    std::cout << "Network destructor" << std::endl;
    my_map.clear();
  }

  void addLogic(uint32_t Id, std::shared_ptr<Logic> lgc) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mutex);
    my_map.insert(std::pair<uint32_t, std::shared_ptr<Logic>>(Id, lgc));
    cv.notify_one();
  }

  void removeLogic(uint32_t Id) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mutex);
    cv.wait(lk, [this]{return !my_map.empty(); });

    auto p = this->my_map.find(roomId);
    if (p != end(this->my_map)) {
      this->my_map.erase(roomId);
    }

    lk.unlock();
  }

 /**
   * Start thread
   */
  void StartThread(int id = 1) {
    running = true;
    first = std::thread([this, id] { process(id); });
    first.detach();
  }

  /**
   * Stop thread
   */
  void StopThread() {
    running = false;
  }

private:
  std::thread first;
  std::atomic<bool> running = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(true);

  void process(int id) {
    while (running) {
      for (const auto& it:my_map) {
        it.second->run();
      }
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
    }
  }    

 private:
  std::mutex mutex;
  std::condition_variable cv;

  using MyMapType = std::map<uint32_t, std::shared_ptr<Logic> >; 

  MyMapType my_map;
  std::string par1;
};
```

Comment: Re, "...there is a synchronization problem in the `process(id)` procedure." There is no synchronization problem _IN_ the procedure. If you have a synchronization problem, the problem is _between_ different threads, one or more of which might call your `process(id)` procedure. But what is the problem? How many threads do you have? What are the threads supposed to do? What is it that you want to _prevent_ them from doing?

Comment: @besmirched two threads. For example, when the run () method is executed, I delete this map element using the removeLogic

Comment: OK, so, you are saying that you want to prevent the main thread from performing `addLogic(...)` or `removeLogic(...)` while the `process(...)` thread is active and vice versa? That's easy. Just have all three methods lock the same mutex.

Comment: P.S.: I would not mess with `std::unique_lock`. I'd stick with `std::lock_guard`.

Comment: Are you concerned about the iteration over the map being interleaved with modification of it?

Comment: @DavisHerring exactly. I'm afraid to remove the map element while its run() method works

Comment: @Max: And is it acceptable to block a deleter until the next `run` finishes?

Comment: @DavisHerring You mean, that don't call deleter, until the run not finished?

Comment: @Max: I mean that if a thread calls `removeLogic`, that it waits until the beginning of the next iteration in `process` before deleting (or returning).

Comment: @DavisHerring I think it is not acceptable. Because run procedure are processing network connection.

Comment: But so far I do not know how to do better

Comment: This may be a case where the best solution is to have the object manage its own lifetime and self-destruct when it's no longer used. Look into `std::shared_ptr`. This allows you to have two different things that extend the object's lifetime and the object will be destroyed when they're both done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first idea is to protect the `map` as a whole with a mutex that is **released** during `run`.  This works for `addLogic` because inserting into a `map` invalidates no iterators, but not for `deleteLogic` which might invalidate the very iterator value being used by `process`.

More efficient, lock-free approaches like hazard pointers may be applicable here, but the basic idea is to use a deferred **deletion list**.  Assuming that the intent of concurrent deletion is cancellation of the task (not merely cleanup after all work is completed), it’s sensible to have the consumer thread to check immediately before execution.  Using a `set` (to correspond to your `map`) will let the deletion list be dynamic and those checks be efficient.

So have **another** `mutex` protect the deletion list and take it at the beginning of each iteration in `process`:

```
  void addLogic(uint32_t Id, std::shared_ptr<Logic> lgc) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mutex);
    my_map.insert(std::pair<uint32_t, std::shared_ptr<Logic>>(Id, lgc));
  }

  void removeLogic(uint32_t Id) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> kg(kill_mutex);
    kill.insert(Id);
  }

private:
  std::set<uint32_t> kill;
  std::mutex mutex,kill_mutex;
  void process(int id) {
    for(;running;std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms)) {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lg(mutex);
      for(auto i=my_map.begin(),e=my_map.end();i!=e;) {
        if(std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(kill_mutex),kill.erase(i->first)) {
          i=my_map.erase(i);
          continue;    // test i!=e again
        }
        lg.unlock();
        i->second->run();
        lg.lock();
        ++i;
      }
    }
  }
```

This code omits your `condition_variable` usage: it’s not necessary to wait before *enqueuing* something for deletion.

Comment: at first glance, my segfault went away. ty again

Answer (score 1):

The solution with low level concurrency primitives usually does not scale and is not easy to maintain.

A better alternative would be to have a thread-safe "control" queue of map update or worker termination instructions.

Something like this:

```
enum Op {
        ADD,
        DROP,
        STOP
};

struct Request {
    Op op;
    uint32_t id;
    std::function<void()> action;
};

...

// the map which required protection in your code
std::map<uint32_t, std::function<void()>> subs;

// requests queue and its mutex (not very optimal, just to demonstrate the idea)
std::vector<Request> requests;
std::mutex mutex;

// the worker thread
std::thread worker([&](){
    // the temporary buffer where requests are drained to from the queue before processing
    decltype(requests) buffer;

    // the main loop
    while (true) {
        // requests collection (requires synchronization)
        {
            std::lock_guard<decltype(mutex)> const guard {mutex};
            buffer.swap(requests);
        }

        // requests processing
        for(auto&& request: buffer) {
            switch (request.op) {
                case ADD:
                    subs[request.id] = std::move(request.action);
                    break;
                case DROP:
                    subs.erase(request.id);
                    break;
                case STOP: goto endloop;
            }
        }

        // map iteration
        for (auto&& entry: subs) {
            entry.second();
        }
    }
    endloop:;
});
```